# Inserting multiple records into MySQL from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I am uploading multiple images via the code below (it works), but I can't insert these images' urls into my database. I tried a few thing but can't make it work. My code is inn't completed yet, so I didn't add controls (filetype, filesize, etc) yet.

index.php

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <div id="file_container">
        <input name="images[]" multiple type="file" id="file[]"/><br/>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

upload.php

```
$target = "upload/";
$test = 1;

foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $value) {
    $path = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // getting the extension

    // creating a unique value here
    $name = md5($name);
    $generate1 = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s:u'));
    $randomizer = uniqid($name);
    $name = $name . $generate1 . $randomizer;
    $makeaname = $target . $name . "." . $ext;

    if ($test == 1) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], $makeaname)) {
            echo "<strong>" . $value . "</strong> successful <br />\n";
            echo $makeaname; // it echoes image urls, so everything is okay so far.
        }
    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
```

I used the query below in a foreach loop after `echo $makeaname;` but it didn't work. I appreciate any kind of help or guidance.

```
$upload_image = $sqli->prepare("INSERT INTO images(image_value, type, size) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$upload_image->bind_param("sss", $makeaname, $_FILES['images']['type'], $_FILES['images']['size']);
$upload_image->execute();
```

Comment: $makeaname is a string of the filename, not the actual file. first, you need to modify your bind_param call from "sss" to be "bss" and second you need to supply the actual file. see https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/php_s_mysqli_extension_storing

Comment: Have you checked for error messages in your query? Also Is this `$_FILES['images']['type']` correct in your bind statement?` In other words, should it be `$_FILES['images']['type'][$key]`?

Comment: @Gohn67, thank you. Now size and type columns can be added perfectly. I also noticed that I forgot to include connect.php file at the top of my file, which was the dumbest thing I've have ever done in 2015. I congratulate myself on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index the `$_FILES` arrays. Also, you don't need to bind a parameter for the `NULL` value, use a `NULL` literal in the SQL (or you can just leave the value out entirely if this is the default in the schema).

```
upload_image = $sqli->prepare("INSERT INTO images(image_value, type, size) VALUES (NULL,?,?)");
$upload_image->bind_param("ss", $type, $size);
foreach ($_FILES['images']['type'] as $i => $type) {
    $size = $_FILES['images']['size'][$i];
    $upload_image->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I already solved my issue but indexing the $_FILES array is a thing I learned here. Thanks. (You can read my comment above, the last one on the question)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your database column "image_value" is a BLOB data type. Then try this code instead:

```
$null = NULL;
$upload_image = $sqli->prepare("INSERT INTO images(image_value, type, size) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$upload_image->bind_param("bss", $null, $_FILES['images']['type'], $_FILES['images']['size']);
$upload_image->send_long_data(0, file_get_contents($makeaname));
$upload_image->execute();
```

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, but I can't make it work. It gives me an array - string conversion error. I am working on it, though. Thank you for your time.